# stapes of connection with irc server

Tags: c, server, client, irc

I developed an irc server program. My problem is that I can take the first half of the connection that is to say I received the nick and user sent by client in my server but when I want to send a message for the client or any response that does not work

```
if ((client_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &size))==-1) {
            //fprintf(stderr,"Accept Failure\n");
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Server got connection from client %s\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));

        buff="RPL_WELCOME";
        send(client_fd,buff, strlen(buff),0);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: RPL_WELCOME isn't an actual command. When the standard says RPL_WELCOME, they mean to look up the code called RPL_WELCOME, and send that code (it's a 3-digit number).

Comment: buff="001";
        send(client_fd,buff, strlen(buff),0);    i did this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

uint32_t some_long =001;

```
uint32_t network_byte_order;

// convert and send
network_byte_order = htonl(some_long);
send(client_fd, &network_byte_order, sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
```

i modified my function send like this and there no a response in client :/